# Extending JavaScript class properties in TypeScript implicitly

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Let's say I have these classes in JavaScript, and I'm trying to convert them to TypeScript:

```js
class Dog {
    tags = {
        barked: true,
    };
}

class Pug extends Dog {
    tags = {
        ...this.tags,
        snorted: true,
    };
}

const pug = new Pug();
```

However, the same code in TypeScript will produce the following error:

```
error TS7022: 'tags' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

The error is pretty clear here. I'm using `this` when re-defining `tags`, so TypeScript is upset.

Is there some alternative way to appease TypeScript? The only way I've thought of thus far is to do as the error suggests, and explicitly typing it. However in much larger type definitions it gets repetitive.

At the end of the day, I have classes with properties that are an object of defined key/value pairs. And each sub-class extends the super's object and adds additional key/values.

Comment: Where it says `... this.events`, you mean `...this.tags` right?

Comment: No. It's not upset that you are using `this`, it is upset that you didn't declare the type of the property (and it couldn't be inferred either). Yes, explicitly type it!

Comment: @Jorjon yes, sorry for the confusion. I was trimming out the actual code to this toy example and accidentally left that error in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, this is the simple solution I'm going with

```js
class DogTags {
    barked = true;
}

class PugTags extends DogTags {
    snorted = true;
}

class Dog {
    tags = new DogTags();
}

class Pug extends Dog {
    tags = new PugTags();
}
```

Truth be told, I'm not a huge fan of this solution. But it correctly models the original question I wanted without using anything too "hacky", such as throwing around a bunch of `as any` TypeScript coercions.

Jorjon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64310411/944727) correctly identified that I'm trying to fix composition paradigms with inheritance. If I could have, a better, inheritance only driven answer would have been this:

```js
class Dog {
    tagBarked = true;
}

class Pug extends Dog {
    tagSnorted = true;
}
```

Typical class inheritance will automatically inherit these attributes and thus no hacky code is needed. However for the large codebase I'm updating from JS to TS, this solution will not work, because for the `Pug` class it's always referred to as `pug.tag.snorted`, and often dynamically too. Once I complete the TS conversion I can start addressing paradigm issues as identified above. But one step at a time.

And finally for any future readers, here's another option not brought up:

```
class Dog {
    getTags = () => ({
        barked: true,
    });

    tags: ReturnType<this["getTags"]> = this.getTags() as any;
}

class Pug extends Dog {
    getTags = () => ({
        ...super.getTags(),
        snorted: true,
    });
}
```

The dynamic explicit typing on `tags` feels very hacky to me, so that's why I did not use it as my solution. Plus I was looking for implicit types. Perhaps this approach's insights will be useful to other developers.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much had it right, but you need to spread the `super`'s tags rather than `this`'s

```
class Pug extends Dog {
    tags = {
        ...super.tags, // <-- change from 'this' to 'super'
        snorted: true,
    };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNT0AuZEwF5UMtSAjMAJwGsBTAEwC4dKBXWgGhMwF8BuNDzRpQkGAAVWyWgA9stAHb0YCZOlK580IutJYAdIYisADrUr7NELnqwQF8SvKYt2NrP0HDg8BRGzQJlLa0Aq0AO7QkogAFACUAkGIlngQ+hQ0DGhJKfj69o7OQA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It certainly _feels_ correct, but it seems there exists a bug in TypeScript. `super.tags` will be `undefined` to runtime in this example, so nothing is actually spread.

To test, just add `console.log(pug.tags.barked);` at the end of the script you linked. You'll see TypeScript thinks it will be the `boolean` type, when in fact it's `undefined` because  the Dog's tags were not actually spread. `super` can only access methods, not properties.

Comment: Dang, I thought that would've worked. Since you pointed out that `super` can only access methods, maybe you could provide a protected method for the subclasses when they want to access the base class's fields, which I've tried [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNT0AuZEwF5UMtSAjMAJwGsBTAEwC4dKBXWgGhMwF8BuNN2gAHSvGy1gE+tES1s0APq58ACgCUqaJXmtKAOxwALAJYQAdCpg9oAelvQAEmGDVoAM3iVoEVmVCQELQw2PDQLsDBMPRguGg8ggFQ0AAKrMi0AB4S+vQwCMjopFbQREWkWOZVvsK0lObKeBAcdg4AqkHGtCJiElIM4cCRUF7asUZ1xmCG2BPQSTDuJrQg9EKkEPpe0szYbJxC-PGJ8PoQCsLppdD6tADuqekaAsCnEPAgtOYgSKqXiJYmuogA).

Comment: It's not a fantastic solution since you'll need to add that protected accessor to each class that you intend to extend, but that's pretty much all I can think of doing

Comment: `super` accesses properties as well. It accesses properties and methods on the prototype. So you are accessing `Dog.prototype.tags`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Answer (score 1):

Even though *you* understand that `Pug`'s `tags` property is dependent on `Dog`'s `tags` property, the compiler sees `tags = {...this.tags}` as circular, and therefore cannot figure out what type it's going to be.  You could, if you want, explicitly annotate `Pug`'s `tags` property like:

```
class PugExplicit extends Dog {
  tags: { snorted: boolean, barked: boolean } = {
    ...this.tags,
    snorted: true,
  };
}
```

But this is cumbersome.  Another way to proceed is to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the `this` inside your `tags` initializer is of type `Dog` and not `Pug`:

```
class Pug extends Dog {
  tags = {
    ...(this as any as Dog).tags,
    snorted: true,
  };
}
```

That has the desired effect of inferring that `Pug`'s `tags` is of type `{snorted: boolean, barked: boolean}` without requiring you to explicitly annotate it.  (I'm not sure why I needed to assert through `any` with `this as any as Dog` instead of just `this as Dog`.  Without the intermediate type, though, the compiler still complains about circularity.  I guess the `this`-ness persists through one assertion but not two?)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNaAXMiYF5UNNoAjMAJwGsBTAEwC5sKBXGgGmIF8BuNLjGlCQYABRaIAogA8ADiACWwBVmg1pWGgDs6MBMnSYceJimgQt8CpsZl48EDTBb2ZSrVul7j59C7RCQxIAOlCsAAsFCGDjCE4Sc0treiYsVg5uPgE0IXAoaHFkdU0dPSQiI1wCCpDQgAoIqOhIZq0AT2ayxABKGKr4kgsrG1T0gd5+HOB4LQhVWQkA6C0aAHcCiTruvmnZhxpgkCQ6hZ6gA)

Comment: Thanks. And yes the later option is nicer. It's actually what I'm currently using, but the `as any` part recently caused an obscure error in my code base so I'm trying to see if there are better solutions I can refactor my code base to.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing inheritance with composition, that's why Typescript doesn't like what you are doing.

The most elegant way, would be to do something like React does.

Each time you extend a class, you pass the properties you are adding as a generic.

For some reason, only works when using a constructor. But maybe someone else can give you a better approach than this.

```
class Dog<T = {}> {
    tags = {
        barked: true,
    } as {barked: boolean} & T;
}

class Pug extends Dog<{snorted: boolean}> {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.tags = {
        ...this.tags,
        snorted: true,
      };
    }
}

const pug = new Pug();
```

[Typescript Plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=6&pln=8&pc=6#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzAPAFWgXmgbwL4D4cAoaU6AFzERi2xLIYCMwAnAawFMATALgpYCuHADT1SuaJBzN23Po3jwQHMADsJAMmioA3EVxEioSDAAKAxNA4APch1VcYCFNgir4LO72gKlK9YR0DMDwqhDkgsDkHgAUAJTEDKQQAgAOHCzxekkUABYAlhAAdJTUmIk50EXV5AXFpRCildBuHl58EUJNSbjZZAYGRqHh0KkW5aocAO7Q5ohZQA)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this later. It seems the issue is that ts types cannot reference themselves.

Just moving the circular reference out will allow ts to know the types.

```
type DogTags = Dog["tags"]
type PugTags = DogTags & Pug["pugTags"]

class Dog {
    tags = {
        barked: true,
    }
}

class Pug extends Dog {

    pugTags = { snorted: true }

    tags: PugTags = {
        ...this.tags,
        ...this.pugTags
    }

    
}

const dog = new Dog();
console.log('dog.tags', dog.tags)

const pug = new Pug();
console.log('pug.tags', pug.tags)
```

[Here is the example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcwCoEMEGcoF5aINoBEwa6BAugFCiRQAKArsidrkxlAGR2OFiOoZyFCgGMANinSZ4CKAG8KUJVGLscC5ZqgAjFACcA1hAAmALhV76EADSLlAXwqPREqd1kQAHsAgA7Y9KI8sKafGyY6lDovnB6PmYWVlDOmqro5gzhLBpaSgB0BcAAFgCW6Hlptrn5haXlYQLodkopyk7CInC%206MBQxkE4vhAA7qwAFACUANyiXehwYhB5YohjAOT9CBUka9Z9iNsYEx1zvWEsQ6OZkzOd3QtLKwjrYYfou1CvacdAA)